# How Do I Put An App I Wrote On My iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am somewhat new the world of Mac and "i" devices. I have an iMac 9 and I am thinking about buying an iPad mini but have read statements on the web that if I write my own app I will go through the App Store to get onto my own iPad and pay a $100 annual fee. How mush truth is there to this? This is very extreme for someone that wants to write apps for my own use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to pay around 100$ (annual) for iOS Developer Program in order to upload Your app to the device. You won't have to upload it via AppStore but directly from Xcode.

You need to pay, because Apple provides You all neccessary Provisioning Profiles, Certificates etc. You'll be able to add up to 100 iDevices to Your account.

Here's [knowledge base](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/) with all informations.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was talking to someone local to me and he said that the $100 is an annual fee to keep the app working on a mobile device once uploaded. Is there any truth to this?  This is why I said this is "very extreme for someone that wants to write apps for my own use".

Comment: I didn't check that, but I don't think Your app will expire. After checking the `.app` folder with `codesign` there's only information when it was signed, not expiration date. But I'm not 100% sure...

Answer (score 1):

If you're not on the latest version of iOS you could also jailbreak your device to be able to deploy iOS apps. This is an [easy tutorial](http://www.grobinson.me/developing-and-debugging-my-own-apps-on-jailbroken-ios8-1-using-xcode-6-1-without-paying-apple/) explaining the process

1. On your Jailbroken device install AppSync Unified 5.2-1 (or later) from AngelXWind’s repo. Don’t use any other AppSync, and if you have others, be sure to remove them.
2. Open `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/SDKSettings.plist` and change AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED to YES. You may need to duplicate it to the desktop, change it, save it, then drag and drop back into the original folder because OS X let you edit the file in place.
3. If XCode was running, restart XCode.
4. Change your Project and Target settings to “Ad Hoc Code Sign” in Build Settings
5. Tell XCode to run app on iPhone. At this point XCode will put app on your iDevice, but can’t debug because it can’t attach to the process. The app will start then close immediately. You can now manually start the app on the phone now though.
6. To enable debugging: In your project select File>New File Property List and create a file called `Entitlements.plist`. Add ``` Can be debugged`` or ```get-task-allow` (both do the same thing) and set the value to YES.
7. Now change your Project and Target Code Signing Entitlements (In Build Settings) to `Entitlements.plist` (you have to type it in).

Comment: An intriguing idea for someone merely seeking to write and use their own apps on their own device. At my current level of experience with iOS I would be afraid of paper-waiting the device. A few months back I read an article that stated that Apple iOS devices only held 20% of the market share. Perhaps Apple could turn this around by allowing people to upload up to 3 apps 'they wrote' themselves to their 'own device' for  free.